# SQL Column with Max Values where seperate column = 1

Tags: sql, max

I have a table similar to below:

```
+-----+-----------+--------+--------+
| key | timestamp | event1 | event2 |
+-----+-----------+--------+--------+
| 123 | 07:06     | 1      | 0      |
| 123 | 07:21     | 1      | 0      |
| 123 | 07:59     | 0      | 1      |
| 123 | 08:02     | 0      | 1      |
| 456 | 14:21     | 1      | 0      |
| 456 | 15:02     | 0      | 1      |
| ... | ...       | ...    | ...    |
+-----+-----------+--------+--------+
```

And I'm looking to get one row for each key, where the next two columns are the **minimum** values of event1 and the **maximum** values of event2, and then (fingers crossed) a delta between the two times.

```
+-----+--------+--------+-------+
| key | event1 | event2 | delta |
+-----+--------+--------+-------+
| 123 | 07:06  | 08:02  | 00:54 |
| 456 | 14:21  | 15:02  | 00:41 |
| ... | ...    | ...    | ...   |
+-----+--------+--------+-------+
```

So far I've tried a `max` function where `event1` = 1 however I get the overall maximum value of `event1` alongside every key value regardless of whether or not that key had that value at any point.

Comment: What is the data type of `timestamp` and what DBMS are you using?

Comment: @RyanP, your database and the datatype of the `timestamp` column may change the answers below slightly.  Please update your question with that information.

Comment: Please consider upvoting, commenting and or marking answer (the checkbox below the vote) to any answer you found helpful or require more information from.

Comment: Hi paqogomez, sorry I've just had the change to test out all three answers. For others reading, I am using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could use multiple CTEs, depending on your RDBMS:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41f9e/5)

```
with mins as (
select
[key],
min([timestamp]) as event1
from
table1
where
[event1] = 1
group by
[key])

,maxes as
(select
[key],
max([timestamp]) as event2
from
table1
where
[event2] = 1
group by 
[key])

select
mins.[key],
mins.event1,
maxes.event2
from
mins
inner join maxes
on mins.[key] = maxes.[key]
```

Calculating the delta will depend on how you're actually storing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Putting them into subselects would accomplish this.

```
select
   e1."key", 
   Convert(varchar(8),min(e1."timestamp"), 108) as event1, 
   Convert(varchar(8), max(e2."timestamp"), 108) as event2, 
   Convert(varchar(8), (max(e2."timestamp") - min(e1."timestamp")), 108) as delta 
from
    (select "key", "timestamp" from table1 where event1 = 1) e1
    inner join (select "key", "timestamp" from table1 where event2 = 1) e2
        on e1."key" = e2."key"
group by e1."key"
```

Edit:

With the help of @Andrew's fiddle I [created my own](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41f9e/24)

Also, changed the formatting, output is:

```
KEY EVENT1      EVENT2      DELTA
123 07:06:00    08:02:00    00:56:00
456 14:21:00    15:02:00    00:41:00
```

Note: `key` and `timestamp` are reserved words on some platforms and would need to be quoted accordingly.  I also made the assumption that `timestamp` was a datetime type, based on your example data.

Comment: That's non-standard SQL (due to the `[..]` "quoting" style). Questions only tagged with `sql` should use standard SQL as much as possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, true.  I was hoping that by now, he'd have listed his platform and I could adjust accordingly.  I removed the brackets.  Do you see any other non standard problems?

Comment: Nitpicking: the standard requires keywords to be quoted using double quotes: so you would have to use `"key"` (which happens to work on SQL Server just as well)

Comment: Thanks paqogomez, as a_horse_with_no_name suggests, I think that quoting style isn't playing nice with SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @RyanP., I've changed the syntax to match what horse suggested.  You didnt specify the platform until now.  Switch back to the `[]` instead of the quotes. And send out some upvotes for those that helped :)

Comment: @RyanP. You can see in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/41f9e/1) that my quoting style works perfectly.  Its also the solution that is the easiest to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using SQL Server syntax only for the *TimeFromParts(...)* and *Right(...) functions for formatting, and standard SQ elswwhere):

```
select
     "key"
    ,right(cast(event1 as char(8)),5) as event1
    ,right(cast(event2 as char(8)),5) as event2
    ,right(timefromparts(0,0,datediff(ss,event1, event2),0,0),5) as delta
from (
    select 
         "key"
        ,min(case when event1=1 then timestamp else cast('23:59:59' as time) end) as event1
        ,max(case when event2=1 then timestamp else cast('00:00:00' as time) end) as event2
    from table1
    group by "key"
) T
;
```

yields from the sample data:

```
key         event1 event2 delta
----------- ------ ------ -----
123         07:06  08:02  00:56
456         14:21  15:02  00:41
```

Comment: You cast `event1 as char`, I think you mean to cast `timestamp`

Comment: Also, I think that timefromparts is only valid in Sql Server 2012.